# Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

My issue is that while submitting the data into the database I am getting error as

> *Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.*

Here is my code:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in ImagesGrid.Rows)
        {
            var title = row.FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
            var description = row.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox;
            var imageFile = row.FindControl("flUpload") as FileUpload;

            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_galleries_stack (gallery_id,img_title,img_desc,img_path,IsDefault) values (@gallery_id,@img_title,@img_desc,@img_path,@IsDefault)", conn);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@gallery_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_title", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = title;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_desc", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = description;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = imageFile;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@IsDefault", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Convert.ToInt32(chkDefault.Checked);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Teachers profile added sucessfully');window.location ='csrgalleriesstack.aspx';", true);
            }

        }
}
```

I tried changing to `Int32` for the checkbox but it is not working.

Comment: **gallery_Id** is int in db and you are passing string

Comment: You don't have to convert `Checked` or `bool` to `int`. Simply assign the `bool` value and it should be converted to `bit`

Comment: @Habib: When I changed galleryId to `SelectedValue`. i am getting error as `Failed to convert parameter value from a TextBox to a String.`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: How to use that then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the issue was not in the `gallery_id`, The issue was, I had to send the `filename` with the path. like this

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "~/Images/" + imageFile.FileName;
```

And that worked for me.

So my final code was like below:-

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        foreach (GridViewRow row in ImagesGrid.Rows)
        {   
            var title = row.FindControl("txtTitle") as TextBox;
            var description = row.FindControl("txtDescription") as TextBox;
            var imageFile = row.FindControl("flUpload") as FileUpload;
            var chkDefault = row.FindControl("chkDefault") as CheckBox;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_galleries_stack (gallery_id,img_title,img_desc,img_path,isDefault) values (@gallery_id,@img_title,@img_desc,@img_path,@isDefault)", conn);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@gallery_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(ddlgallery.SelectedValue);
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = title.Text;
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = description.Text;
                if (imageFile.HasFile)
                {
                    imageFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/GalleryImages/") + imageFile.FileName);
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@img_path", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "~/GalleryImages/" + imageFile.FileName;
                }
                cmd1.Parameters.Add("@IsDefault", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkDefault.Checked;
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Teachers profile added sucessfully');window.location ='csrgalleriesstack.aspx';", true);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like problem on that line;

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add("@gallery_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text;
```

`SelectedItem.Text` is `string` but you try to insert that value to an int column since you typed as `SqlDbType.Int`.

If your column is *already* a character typed, you need to use the right `SqlDbType` enum value. But since your parameter name `gallery_id`, I strongly suspect it is a numeric value. In such a case, you need to convert that `ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text` value to `Int32` if it is a valid integer.

Also as Habib [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834530/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-string-to-a-int32-error#comment45938592_28834530), you don't need to use `Convert.ToInt32` in your last parameter. Since `Checked` returns `bool`, it is correctly [mapped](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) with `Bit` type on SQL Server.

And use `using` statement for your `SqlConnection` as you did for `SqlCommand`.

Comment: I tried giving as `SelectedValue` then too it was giving error

Comment: @RahulSutar I think `SelectedValue` still returns `string`. How about convert to your result to `int` as `Convert.ToInt32(ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text)` if it is a valid integer?

Comment: tried with your way, getting error as `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: @RahulSutar What is the value of `ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text` when you debug your code? Sounds like is not a valid integer. Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: I get proper value when I write like this `ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text;` After that I get error as `Input string was not in a correct format.` at line `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @RahulSutar `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't throw `FormatException`. It is clearly somewhere else. But since didn't tell us what is the value of `ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text`, we never know what is the real problem.

Comment: I am geting exact value what I selected for that dropdownlist at `ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text;`. But still i am getting error as `Input string was not in a correct format.` at `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Convert.ToInt32(ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text);` instead of passing Text directly?

Answer (score 0):

`ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Text` is causing problem for you.

Try `ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Value`, even if it gives you a problem, then try

`Convert.ToInt32(ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Value)`.

Usually `dropdown lists` show text in the front end, but they have an integer value associated with them, which can be extracted using `ddlgallery.SelectedItem.Value`

Regards